# How to implement $group aggregate code in mongo java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to use mongo aggregate in Java, but I cannot define `$group` code as:

In javascript:

```
$group = {
        '_id':null,
        'money_bank':{
            '$sum':{
                '$cond':[{'$eq'=>{'$type':'bank'}},'$amount',0]
            }
          }
```

In java:

```
BasicDBList eqList = new BasicDBList();
eqList.add("$type");
eqList.add("bank");
DBObject eqObject = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$eq", eqList).get();

BasicDBList condList = new BasicDBList();
condList.add(eqObject);
condList.add("$amount");
condList.add(0);
DBObject conObj = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$cond", condList).get();
DBObject sumObj = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$sum", conObj).get();
DBObject moneyObj = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("money_bank", sumObj).get();
DBObject idObj = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("_id", null).get();
BasicDBList groupList = new BasicDBList();
groupList.add(idObj);
groupList.add(moneyObj);
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupList);
```

But when I executed code, the error:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: a group's fields must be specified in an object"
```

Please help me in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You've slightly misunderstood the correct way to turn this into a Java call, two of the places you've used a `BasicDBList` you actually needed to use a `BasicDBObject` instead - that's what that error means, it means you need to use an object not a list.

I've made the change to your code, but I haven't tested it against MongoDB, I leave that up to you.

The minimal changes needed to give you the equivalent of the Javascript is:

```
BasicDBObject eqArgs = new BasicDBObject("$type", "bank");
DBObject eqObject = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$eq", eqArgs).get();

BasicDBList condList = new BasicDBList();
condList.add(eqObject);
condList.add("$amount");
condList.add(0);
DBObject conObj = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$cond", condList).get();
DBObject sumObj = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$sum", conObj).get();
BasicDBObject groupArgs = new BasicDBObject();
groupArgs.append("_id", null);
groupArgs.append("money_bank", sumObj);
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupArgs);

// Using an assert to check it's correct, remove in production code
Assert.assertThat(group.toString(), is("{ \"$group\" : { \"_id\" :  null  , " +
                                                        "\"money_bank\" : { " +
                                                            "\"$sum\" : { " +
                                                                "\"$cond\" : [ { \"$eq\" : { \"$type\" : \"bank\"}} , " +
                                                                "\"$amount\" , 0]" +
                                                            "}" +
                                                        "}" +
                                                       "}" +
                                       "}"));
```

However you can simplify it even more (although I admit the Java is still uglier than the JavaScript):

```
BasicDBList condList = new BasicDBList();
condList.add(new BasicDBObject("$eq", new BasicDBObject("$type", "bank")));
condList.add("$amount");
condList.add(0);
DBObject sumObj = new BasicDBObject("$sum", new BasicDBObject("$cond", condList));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id", null).append("money_bank", sumObj));
```

For some reason the BasicDBObjectBuilder is more verbose than using BasicDBObject.

Comment: I propose to use com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse function and pass in the query to get a DBObject without any pain :)

Comment: That's doing String manipulation, it's still going to have horrible performance.

Comment: @Trisha,thank you, but when i using $or in $cond that running but return incorrect result. Please help me $group in java code: PHP code is: $group = array(
            '_id'=>null,
            'sms_card'=>array(
                '$sum'=>array(
                    '$cond'=>array(
                        array(
                            '$or'=>array(
                                    array('$eq'=>array('$type','sms')),
                                    array('$eq'=>array('$type','card'))
                                )),'$amount',0)
                )
            )

Comment: @Trisha - dont understand your comment. you meant using the com.ibm.mongodb.util.JSON is not a good idea?